# How to implement content track using piwik/matomo + angulartics2

Tags: angular, angular6, matomo, angulartics2

**Technology** Angular 6.0.9, Angular CLI: 6.0.8
**Plugin** [angulartics2](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2) ^6.2.0
**Vendor plugin** [angulartics-piwik](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/tree/master/src/lib/providers/piwik)

I'm about to capture my page specific block content into piwik/matomo using angulartics2 but I can't figure out OR unable to do that.

I reviewed the plugin code from [github](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/blob/master/src/lib/providers/piwik/piwik.ts) So, I think that it seems like no support given by angulartics2 for block content kinds of stuff.

I also drill into matomo given introduction about How to [Content Tracking](https://developer.matomo.org/guides/content-tracking) and I'm now helpless. However, event tracking is working fine!

Can anybody tell me that I'm on wrong way OR How to accomplish that?

HTML Example:

```
<div data-track-content>
    <div [data-content-name]="data.name">{{data.name}}</div>
    <span [data-content-piece]="data.catalog">{{data.catalog}}</span>
    <span [data-content-target]="data.path"></span>
    /*
    Also tried below structure but it's not working too:
        <div data-content-name>{{data.name}}</div>
        <span data-content-piece>{{data.catalog}}</span>
        <a href="www.example.com" data-content-target>Buy Now</a>
    */
</div>
```

Please...
Help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Would love to understand this, too.

Comment: @Jolly Let me explain it in very simplest way. How to implement content track using angulartics2 + piwik?